# Study the following series of functions:

Tags: real-analysis, convergence-divergence, solution-verification, power-series

Given $\alpha\in\mathbb{R}$ define the series of powers:
$$f(x)=\sum_{n=1}^{+\infty}\Big(\frac{n+1}{n}\Big)^{n^2}(\alpha x+1)^n$$
First of all, find the radius of convergence. This can be done easly via the root method:
$$\lim_n \Bigg(\Big(\frac{n+1}{n}\Big)^{n^2}(\alpha x+1)^n\Bigg)^\frac{1}{n}=e(\alpha x +1) < 1$$
where the inequality yields the radius of convergence: $R_{\alpha}=\frac{1-e}{e\alpha}$ and $\alpha<0$ as we must have $R_{\alpha}>0$.

Second point now is: for which set of values of $\alpha$ the series converges to at least one positive real value. As we are dealing with a series of power, in this cases it suffices to have the base greater than $0$:
$$\alpha x+1>0$$
from which $x<-\frac{1}{\alpha}$. I was thinking now to impose $\alpha<R_{\alpha}$ to obtain such set, but it gives the empty set as result. Am I doing something wrong?

Next step would be to find a set of $\alpha$ such that the series converges to at least one positive and one negative value, how do I proceed?
Thanks

Comment: f(x) is defined by a series.   However your analysis is about the sequence.  Sequence must converge to 0 for possibility of series convergence.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The term "radius of convergence" (ROC) is for power series.  Your series is not a power series as written, so the first order of business is get it in power series form.

Assume $\alpha\ne 0.$ Then the series is

$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(1+1/n)^{n^2}\alpha^n(x-(-1/\alpha))^n.$$

That's a power series based at $-1/\alpha.$ To find the ROC, we compute

$$\lim_{n\to \infty} \left |(1+1/n)^{n^2}\alpha^n\right|^{1/n} = e|\alpha|.$$

Thus the ROC is $1/(e|\alpha|).$

The special case is $\alpha =0,$ where you can see the series diverges for every $x$ without going through the above procedure.